# Has anyone used Google Gears in an Enterprise scenario?

Tags: web-applications, google-gears

I want to create an application which will have a client and server components. The client may not be connected to the internet all the time, and hence will have to store data locally and then sync with the server whenever the internet connection is available. The data sync will be both ways: client to server and server to client.

Initially i thought making use of SQL Server Merge replication/Microsoft sync framework for ado.net and creating the client application using C# windows forms.

But Google Gears appears like a very good option, because it works with JavaScript and we just need build a asp.net web application which can then be used both on the client and the server. Plus it is available on Windows mobile 5 and 6, hence available on mobile devices as well.

But has any one used Google Gears in an enterprise scenario? Has any one faced any issues using Google Gears?

Comment: Shame this question hasn't had any attention. Good qn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was evaluating its use for offline document storage for a documentation review application that I was working on at a previous company. We did descide to use it but the company got bought out and the projects went off into the void.

But currently I know google just started using google gears for gmail. And I will add that I don't think it is a bad move, but I would be concerned about the overall penetration, would you be able to force users to have it installed?

Answer (score 3):

Google have put Gears in hibernation mode in favour of HTML5: http://gearsblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/hello-html5.html.

Answer (score 0):

do you think that gmail isn't enterprise? I know gmail can tell google about any issue, but take another example: myspace or remember the milk. I love remember the milk and I consider this an enterprise product.

we have in our "project queue" make and offline application, and the options were: Gear or air, and we choose gears since we think you have many other resources you can use. like prototype, jquery, etc. this is something you should also think about.